# Change the layout order with media queries

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

This is an example of the desktop version on the left and the mobile version on the right.

[image]

On desktop I want to put the div 2 on the right and separating the parent div into two sections, I have tried flexbox (shrink, grow, directions...) but I was unable to achieve this result.

Is it even possible to do?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it’s possible but please give your html code in your question. The structure of that will determine how best to do the two layouts. You can investigate grid.

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
}
.one {
  grid-area: one;
}
.two {
  grid-area: two;
}
.three {
  grid-area: three;
}
.four {
  grid-area: four;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container{
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "one"
      "two"
      "three"
      "four";
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "one two"
      "three two"
      "four two";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class=one>1
  </div>
  <div class=two>2
  </div>
  <div class=three>3
  </div>
  <div class=four>4
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by combining `flex` and `grid` alongside tailwind `breakpoints`. So on mobile devices is just flex column and on desktop is grid with 2 columns and 3 rows where second element spans across the three rows:

```
    <div className="flex flex-col md:grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-3">
        <div className="border-2 border-indigo-600 p-3">1</div>
        <div className="border-2 border-indigo-600 p-3 col-start-2 row-span-3">
          2
        </div>
        <div className="border-2 border-indigo-600 p-3">3</div>
        <div className="border-2 border-indigo-600 p-3">4</div>
      </div>
```

Here's a link to test: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-epcw4d?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Findex.js